# Увеличение / уменьшение масштабирования к позиции мыши на изображении

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Хочу сделать так, чтобы масштабирование фото шло к тем координатам, где находится курсор мыши.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самое простое можно сделать с помощью библиотеки [jQuery Zoom](https://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/)

Или вот пример на чистом javascript

```js
function zoomIn(event) {
  var element = document.getElementById("overlay");
  element.style.display = "inline-block";
  var img = document.getElementById("imgZoom");
  var posX = event.offsetX ? (event.offsetX) : event.pageX - img.offsetLeft;
  var posY = event.offsetY ? (event.offsetY) : event.pageY - img.offsetTop;
  element.style.backgroundPosition = (-posX * 4) + "px " + (-posY * 4) + "px";

}

function zoomOut() {
  var element = document.getElementById("overlay");
  element.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#overlay {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url('https://blogs.esa.int/space19plus/files/2019/03/nebula.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<img id="imgZoom" width="200px" height="200px" onmousemove="zoomIn(event)" onmouseout="zoomOut()" src="https://blogs.esa.int/space19plus/files/2019/03/nebula.jpg">
<div id="overlay" onmousemove="zoomIn(event)"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Я прогуглил весь интернет, и у меня получилось найти.
Оставлю скрип для подрастающего поколения.

**JS**

```
    <script>
    const view = (() => {
  const matrix = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]; // current view transform
  var m = matrix;             // alias 
  var scale = 1;              // current scale
  const pos = { x: 0, y: 0 }; // current position of origin
  var dirty = true;
  const API = {
    applyTo(el) {
      if (dirty) { this.update() }
      el.style.transform = `matrix(${m[0]},${m[1]},${m[2]},${m[3]},${m[4]},${m[5]})`;
    },
    update() {
      dirty = false;
      m[3] = m[0] = scale;
      m[2] = m[1] = 0;
      m[4] = pos.x;
      m[5] = pos.y;
    },
    pan(amount) {
      if (dirty) { this.update() }
       pos.x += amount.x;
       pos.y += amount.y;
       dirty = true;
    },
    scaleAt(at, amount) { // at in screen coords
      if (dirty) { this.update() }
      scale *= amount;
      pos.x = at.x - (at.x - pos.x) * amount;
      pos.y = at.y - (at.y - pos.y) * amount;
      dirty = true;
    },
  };
  return API;
})();


document.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseEvent, {passive: false});
document.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseEvent, {passive: false});
document.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseEvent, {passive: false});
document.addEventListener("mouseout", mouseEvent, {passive: false});
document.addEventListener("wheel", mouseWheelEvent, {passive: false});
const mouse = {x: 0, y: 0, oldX: 0, oldY: 0, button: false};
function mouseEvent(event) {
    if (event.type === "mousedown") { mouse.button = true }
    if (event.type === "mouseup" || event.type === "mouseout") { mouse.button = false }
    mouse.oldX = mouse.x;
    mouse.oldY = mouse.y;
    mouse.x = event.pageX;
    mouse.y = event.pageY;
    if(mouse.button) { // pan
        view.pan({x: mouse.x - mouse.oldX, y: mouse.y - mouse.oldY});
        view.applyTo(zoomMe);
    }
    event.preventDefault();
}
function mouseWheelEvent(event) {
    const x = event.pageX - (zoomMe.width / 2);
    const y = event.pageY - (zoomMe.height / 2);
    if (event.deltaY < 0) { 
        view.scaleAt({x, y}, 1.1);
        view.applyTo(zoomMe);
    } else { 
        view.scaleAt({x, y}, 1 / 1.1);
        view.applyTo(zoomMe);
    }
    event.preventDefault();
}
    </script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div> <img id="zoomMe" class="zoomables" src="Путь к файлу"> </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#zoomMe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```